# Jenkins: aggregating matrix build results

Tags: jenkins, matrix, aggregate

I use Jenkins matrix to run a bunch of tests in parallel. There is a file that is a result of the test. After finishing all the tests, I want to place all resulting files in one workspace on one build agent and do some analysis.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('TestEm') {
            matrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'i'
                        values '1','2','3','4'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Test') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Do Test for $i"
                            sh """
                               sleep 10
                               echo Test for $i > ${i}.txt
                            """
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Aggregate results") {
            agent any
            steps {
               // do the magic and get 1.txt .. 4.txt here, in this workspace
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Couldn't figure out how can I do the magic and collect all the results of the matrix in last step though.

Answer (score 0):

Did it using builtin [stash/unstash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build). Just put `stash includes: '*.txt', name: "$i"` in the test stage and `unstash '1'` and so on in the aggregate stage.